# Why are these two divs not acting as block?

Tags: css, html

I want these 2 div tags so they are on top of each other. I have defined both of them as inline blocks because I need to give them properties like float, padding, border. Even after defining both the div tags as inline-block both of them are partially on same line.
Help appreciated :)!

```
 <div id="legend" style="border:1px solid black; max-width:75%; float:right; display:inline-block;">
     <table style="padding: 2px;">
        <tr>
            <td><span  style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">*</span></td>
            <td>some text goes here.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span  style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">**</span></td>
            <td>Some text goes here again</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span  style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">**</span></td>
            <td>yup..some other text goes here again.dfdsfdsfsf</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="backToSearch"style = "display:inline-block;">
    <button id="btnBackToSearch" class="k-button k-button-icontext"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrowhead-w"></span> Back To <span data-bind="text: backButtonText"></span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need to specify `style = "display:inline-block;"` as `div`s are block level elements. Also `style="border:1px solid black; max-width:75%; float:right; display:inline-block;">` in your first div there is `float:right`.

Comment: Also, floating element will make them try to be on the same line.

Comment: 1+ for that @SteynvanEsveld. But I need the upper div to float to right...what could be done to avoid it from stepping on other div tag ?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/kLt26qdc/

Comment: thanks @KhanhTO I did not know about the clear property! But...there is like some space in between these tags now. How can I make that go away ?

Comment: @HereToLearn_: that's because of `<br/>`

Comment: duhh! Thanks a lot!! This is exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot @KhanhTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<div id="legend" style="border:1px solid black; max-width:75%; float:right;">
    <table style="padding: 2px;">
        <tr>
            <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">*</span>
            </td>
            <td>some text goes here.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">**</span>
            </td>
            <td>Some text goes here again</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">**</span>
            </td>
            <td>yup..some other text goes here again.dfdsfdsfsf</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="backToSearch">
    <button id="btnBackToSearch" class="k-button k-button-icontext"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrowhead-w"></span> Back To <span data-bind="text: backButtonText"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cj1s9q0g/

**Changes**:

- Remove `display:inline-block` as `div` is block by default and block will be on top of each other.
- Add a div with `clear:both` to clear the `float:right`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for working thru with me :)!

Answer (score 1):

`display:inline-block;` sets them *in* the same *line*..

Set them as `display:block;`, and they should be on top of each other

**EDIT:** As @Khanh TO says; Divs are `display:block;` as default, so you don't need to write that.

Comment: `div` is `display:block` by default, we don't even need to set a display rule

Comment: Take a look at this js fiddle @KhanhTO https://jsfiddle.net/06jmv4g7/ . As you can see its not on top of each other.

Comment: @HereToLearn_: that's because of the `float:right` rule

Answer (score 0):

Set them as
display:block;
clear:both;